# Having trouble accessing the nested values of my object. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, dictionary, object, nested

So I am trying to create a function that will list all the stats of a specific player in below object. I am simply trying to return the nested object associated with the playerName itself. I'm guessing map isn't working for me here. Instead I am returning an array of the individual letters of the name "Jeff Adrien". Can someone help me understand where I am going wrong?

```
//Code in question
function playerStats(playerName) {
    let specificPlayer = allPlayers().players

    if (playerName === specificPlayer) {
        return specificPlayer
    }
    const stats = Object.values(playerName).map((nums) => {
        return [nums]
    })
    return stats.flat()
}

console.log(playerStats('Jeff Adrien'))

// details

function allPlayers() {
    const everyPlayer = Object.assign(homePlayers, awayPlayers)
    return everyPlayer
}

const gameObject = () => {
    return {
        home: {
            teamName: 'Brooklyn Nets',
            colors: ['black', 'white'],
            players: {
                'Alan Anderson': {
                    number: 0,
                    shoe: 16,
                    points: 22,
                    rebounds: 12,
                    assists: 12,
                    steals: 3,
                    blocks: 1,
                    slamDunks: 1,
                },

                'Reggie Evans': {
                    number: 30,
                    shoe: 14,
                    points: 12,
                    rebounds: 12,
                    assists: 12,
                    steals: 12,
                    blocks: 12,
                    slamDunks: 7,
                },
                'Brook Lopez': {
                    number: 11,
                    shoe: 17,
                    points: 17,
                    rebounds: 19,
                    assists: 10,
                    steals: 3,
                    blocks: 1,
                    slamDunks: 15,
                },
                'Mason Plumlee': {
                    number: 1,
                    shoe: 19,
                    points: 26,
                    rebounds: 12,
                    assists: 6,
                    steals: 3,
                    blocks: 8,
                    slamDunks: 5,
                },
                'Jason Terry': {
                    number: 31,
                    shoe: 15,
                    points: 19,
                    rebounds: 2,
                    assists: 2,
                    steals: 4,
                    blocks: 11,
                    slamDunks: 1,
                },
            },
        },

        away: {
            teamName: 'Charlotte Hornets',
            colors: ['turquoise', 'purple'],
            players: {
                'Jeff Adrien': {
                    number: 4,
                    shoe: 18,
                    points: 10,
                    rebounds: 1,
                    assists: 1,
                    steals: 2,
                    blocks: 7,
                    slamDunks: 2,
                },

                'Bismak Biyombo': {
                    number: 0,
                    shoe: 16,
                    points: 12,
                    rebounds: 4,
                    assists: 7,
                    steals: 7,
                    blocks: 15,
                    slamDunks: 10,
                },
                'DeSagna Diop': {
                    number: 4,
                    shoe: 14,
                    points: 24,
                    rebounds: 12,
                    assists: 12,
                    steals: 4,
                    blocks: 5,
                    slamDunks: 5,
                },
                'Ben Gordon': {
                    number: 8,
                    shoe: 15,
                    points: 33,
                    rebounds: 3,
                    assists: 2,
                    steals: 1,
                    blocks: 1,
                    slamDunks: 0,
                },
                'Brendan Haywood': {
                    number: 33,
                    shoe: 15,
                    points: 6,
                    rebounds: 12,
                    assists: 12,
                    steals: 22,
                    blocks: 5,
                    slamDunks: 12,
                },
            },
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wow I was trying to work with an array and turn it into an object somehow.. it just clicked for me

```
function playerStats(playerName) {
    for (const player in allPlayers()) {
        if (player === playerName) {
            return allPlayers()[player]
        }
    }
}
```